# Random list of ones and zeros with minimum distance between ones

Tags: python, list

I would like to have a random list where the occurence of ones is 10% and the rest of the items are zeros. The length of this list is 1000. I would like for the values to be in a random order so that there is an adjustable minimum distance between ones. So for example if I choose a value of 3, the list would look something like this:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...]
```

What is the most elegant way to achieve this?

Edit. I was asked for more information and to show some effort.

This is for a study where 0 signifies one type of stimulus and 1 an other kind of stimulus and we want to have a minimum distance between stimulus type 1.

So far I have achieved this with:

```
trials = [0]*400
trials.extend([1]*100)
random.shuffle(trials)

#Make sure a fixed minimum number of standard runs follow each deviant
i = 0
while i < len(trials):
    if trials[i] == 1: 
        trials[i+1:i+1] = 5*[0]
        i = i + 6
    else:
        i = i + 1
```

This gives me a list of length 1000 but to me seems a little clumsy so out of curiosity I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Should there always be exactly 100 ones in the list, or should there be some small random variation in the total number of ones? The latter may be more "authentic", for the same reason that flipping a fair coin 100 times doesn't always give you exactly fifty heads, but it may be harder to implement.

Comment: Could possibly be better placed over at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is it a quiz or homework or can you present an actual usecase for that. Anyway, SO is not a code writing service, so show at least some effort solving the problem.

Comment: @Kevin I edited the question and yes there should be exactly 100 ones.

Comment: Is this in Python 3.6 or what version is this ?

Comment: @MooingRawr Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

You have essentially a binomial random variable. The waiting time between successes for a binomial random variable is given by the negative binomial distribution. Using this distribution, we can get a random sequence of intervals between successes for a binomial variable with the specified success rate. Then we simply add your "refractory period" to all intervals and create a binary representation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import nbinom

min_failures = 3 # refractory period
total_successes = 100
total_time = 1000

# create a negative binomial distribution to model the waiting times to the next success for a Bernoulli RV;
rv = nbinom(1, total_successes / float(total_time))

# get interval lengths between successes;
intervals = rv.rvs(size=total_successes)

# get event times
events = np.cumsum(intervals)

# rescale event times to fit into the total time - refractory time
total_refractory = total_successes * min_failures
remaining_time = total_time - total_refractory
events = events.astype(np.float) / np.max(events) * remaining_time

# add refractory periods
intervals = np.diff(np.r_[0, events])
intervals += min_failures
events = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(intervals[:-1])] # series starts with success

# create binary representation
binary = np.zeros((total_time), dtype=np.uint8)
binary[events.astype(np.int)] = 1
```

To check that the inter-event intervals match your expectations, plot a histogram:

```
# check that intervals match our expectations
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.hist(intervals, bins=20, normed=True);
ax.set_xlabel('Interval length')
ax.set_ylabel('Normalised frequency')
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(np.r_[xticks, min_failures])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: There needs to be exactly 10%, not as a chance. So the amount of 1s has to be == length*0.10

Comment: Major edit. Same approach, but yields not 100 guaranteed successes within the allotted time.

Comment: My English. I meant: Major edit. Same approach, but yields **now** 100 guaranteed successes within the allotted time.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem is to maintain a list of candidate positions from which the next position is chosen randomly. Then, the surrounding range of positions is checked to be empty. If so, this position is chosen and the whole range around it in which no future position is allowed is removed from the list of available candidates. This ensures a minimum number of loops.

It may happen (if `mindist` is big compared to the number of positions) that less than the required positions are returned. In this case, the function needs to be called again, like shown.

```
import random

def array_ones(mindist, length_array, numones):
    result = [0]*length_array
    candidates = range(length_array)
    while sum(result) < numones and len(candidates) > 0:
        # choose one position randomly from candidates
        pos = candidates[random.randint(0, len(candidates)-1)]
        L = pos-mindist if pos >= mindist else 0
        U = pos+mindist if pos <= length_array-1-mindist else length_array-1
        if sum(result[L:U+1]) == 0:  # no taken positions around
            result[pos] = 1
            # remove all candidates around this position
            no_candidates = set(range(L, U+1))
            candidates = list(set(candidates).difference(no_candidates))
    return result, sum(result)


def main():
    numones = 5
    numtests = 50
    mindist = 4

    while True:
        arr, ones = array_ones(mindist, numtests, numones)
        if ones == numones:
           break
    print arr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The function returns the array of ones and it's number of ones. Set difference is used to remove a range of candidate positions noniteratively.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there wasn't a very simple one-line answer to this problem. I finally came up with this:

```
import numpy as np

def construct_list(n_zeros, n_ones, min_distance):
    if min_distance > (n_zeros + n_ones) / n_ones:
        raise ValueError("Minimum distance too high.")

    initial_zeros = n_zeros - min_distance * n_ones
    block = np.random.permutation(np.array([0]*initial_zeros + [1]*n_ones))
    ones = np.where(block == 1)[0].repeat(min_distance)

    #Insert min_distance number of 0s after each 1
    block = np.insert(block, ones+1, 0)

    return block.tolist()
```

This seems simpler than the other answers although Paul's answer was just a little faster with values n_zeros=900, n_ones=100, min_distance=3